# How can serialize bulk data by using DataContractJsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, datacontractserializer

I am serializing bulk data by using  DataContractJsonSerializer but it is encountering error 
viz. **Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.**

```
public static string MyDataContractJsonSerializer(object objToSerialize, Type objType)
{
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(objType);
        System.IO.MemoryStream st1 = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        ser.WriteObject(st1, objToSerialize);  //Error encountering here.. Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
        byte[] barray = st1.ToArray(); 
        string abc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(barray);
        return abc;
}
```

How can i resolve this problem?

Please tell me any alternate way to serialize bulk data.

Please help me.

Comment: What do you want to do with the serialized data? Save it to a file? Send it over the wire? Something else? I highly doubt that you want to keep it in memory. If the data is large you might run into problems.

Comment: i want to send it to javascript (client browser).

Comment: I am sending a message to get data from database by using ajax and wants response.

Comment: Sir, objToSerilize contains large data like 10000 rows in DataSet.

Comment: Is it necessary to send that much data back?

Comment: Yeah, I want to populate a table by using javascript and HTML and also want to cache it client side.

Comment: Well, if you are committed to that approach, it might pay to experiment with a different JSON serializer. Try [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) - it is faster than the Microsoft serializer, though I don't know whether it is more memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the size of the object to serialize is unbounded.

If it's a large object, you'd better to break it into smaller chunks and serialize them one by one.

Comment: it is not possible because of object does not contain more memeber. i mean, object have only two member eg. obj.dataTb and obj.isSuccess. and and length obj.dataTb is exceeding.

Comment: You can break up obj.dataTb to chunks and each chunk contains several rows.

Comment: 100 rows a chunk? 1000 rows a chunk? The number is entirely up to you.

Comment: A single row can contain bulk data. so that it will not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments section you mentioned that you want to send the serialized data to the client browser (javascript client). In this case you should not be serializing the object into a `MemoryStream`. That's a useless waste of memory. If this is an ASP.NET application you could directly serialize the object to the `Response.OutputStream`.

For example your method could look like this:

```
public static void MyDataContractJsonSerializer(
    object objToSerialize, 
    Type objType, 
    Stream output
)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(objType);
    ser.WriteObject(output, objToSerialize);
}
```

and then when invoking the method directly pass the response output stream. For example if you are calling this method from a generic ASHX handler:

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        var objToSerialize = ...

        SerializerClass.MyDataContractJsonSerializer(
            objToSerialize, 
            objToSerialize.GetType(), 
            context.Response.OutputStream
        );
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right sir..it is possible to write directly in context. but ser.WriteObject(output, objToSerialize); is encountering error "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
"
What is solution for above.

Comment: You are getting an `OutOfMemoryException` even if you don't use a MemoryStream but are writing directly to the Response?

Answer (score 0):

You can also serialize to a stream (i.e. FileStream). This way you can serialize gigabytes of data without OutOfMemory exception.

```
        public static void Serialize<T>(T obj, string path)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(path);
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
        }

        public static T Deserialize<T>(string path)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            Stream stream = File.OpenRead(path);
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }
```